# Strange issue with library media voices in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system, elementor

I have an issue, do any of you know why voices in media library don’t show when I try to add an image but they show only in over?

theme installed: hello theme by Elementor
Wp version: 6.1.1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ZbA.jpg
this is what I see when I enter in media library and try to add an image (all blank)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0pVk.jpg
these are voices that shows when I put mouse in blank space

Comment: Hey Roberta, It's very difficult to debug your issue without some demo.

Comment: Voices? Do you maybe mean thumbnail images?

Comment: thanks a lot for the replies. I mean just the tabs in the media library